# Asynchronous WinBioVerify vs WinBioVerifyWithCallback

Tags: c++, windows, windows-7, biometrics

I wrote a program that runs in Windows 8.1 & 10 to verify a fingerprint against the currently logged in user's identity using WinBioVerify. I do this asynchronously by starting the session with WinBioAsyncOpenSession. I tried to run the same program on Windows 7, and it turns out that WinBioAsyncOpenSession doesn't exist in the Win7 version of WinBio.dll.

This shouldn't have been a problem, since it was easy enough to make a separate EXE for Win7 that opened the session normally and called WinBioVerifyWithCallback instead. The problem I'm having now has the same symptoms as when the original program was not properly setting the application's window focus: the fingerprint unit lights up when touched, but no result is returned to the code.

A Google search turns up some references that SetForegroundWindow() is unreliable in Win7, but none of the alternatives I've tried have worked either (BringWindowToTop, AttachThreadInput, WinBioAcquireFocus) assuming the focus is even the problem.

Does anyone have or know of any working examples of WinBioVerifyWithCallback on Windows 7?

EDITED TO ADD:

Here's the code that works (on Win8.1/Win10):

```
unsigned int verifyUser(string &userName) {

string libPath;

OutputDebugString("verifyUser: getApplicationPath");

libPath = getApplicationPath();

    try {

    //Make sure path ends with backslash
    if (libPath[libPath.length()-1] != '\\') libPath += "\\";
    string  userHash = getHash(userName);

    //Get timeout from globals
    int timeoutValue = globals.timeout * 1000;

    //Check to see if we need an infinite timeout
    if (globals.disable_timeout) 
    {
        timeoutValue = 1000 * 60 * 5;
    }
    TotalTickCount = timeoutValue; //5 minutes
    startTick = GetTickCount();
    globals.last_scan_result = BIO_INPROGRESS;
    countdownTimer = SetTimer(hMainWnd, ID_COUNTDOWN, 1000, NULL);

    CString lsr;
    lsr.Format("globals.last_scan_result = %d", globals.last_scan_result);
    OutputDebugString(lsr);

    sessionHandle = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = WinBioAsyncOpenSession(
        WINBIO_TYPE_FINGERPRINT,    // Service provider
        WINBIO_POOL_SYSTEM,         // Pool type
        WINBIO_FLAG_DEFAULT,        // Configuration and access
        NULL,                       // Array of biometric unit IDs
        0,                          // Count of biometric unit IDs
        NULL,                       // Database ID
        WINBIO_ASYNC_NOTIFY_MESSAGE,// Notification method
        hMainWnd,                   // Target window
        WM_APP+BIO_INPROGRESS,      // Message code
        NULL,                       // Callback routine
        NULL,                       // User data
        FALSE,                      // Asynchronous open
        &sessionHandle              // [out] Session handle
    );
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        CString s;
        s.Format("WinBioAsyncOpenSession failed. hr = 0x%x\n", hr);
        OutputDebugString(s);
        KillTimer(hMainWnd, countdownTimer);
        ShowWindow(hMainWnd, SW_HIDE);
        LockSetForegroundWindow(LSFW_UNLOCK);
        if (sessionHandle != NULL)
        {
            WinBioCloseSession(sessionHandle);
            sessionHandle = NULL;
        }
        return BIO_ERROR;
    }

    // Find the identity of the user.
    WINBIO_IDENTITY identity = { 0 };
    hr = GetCurrentUserIdentity(&identity);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        CString s;
        s.Format("User identity not found. hr = 0x%x\n", hr);
        OutputDebugString(s);
        KillTimer(hMainWnd, countdownTimer);
        ShowWindow(hMainWnd, SW_HIDE);
        LockSetForegroundWindow(LSFW_UNLOCK);
        if (sessionHandle != NULL)
        {
            WinBioCloseSession(sessionHandle);
            sessionHandle = NULL;
        }
        return BIO_USER_NOT_ENROLLED;
    }

    // Verify a biometric sample.
    WINBIO_UNIT_ID unitId = 0;
    WINBIO_REJECT_DETAIL rejectDetail = 0;
    BOOLEAN match = FALSE;
    OutputDebugString("Calling WinBioVerify");
    SetWindowText(hStaticWnd, "To sign in, scan your finger on the fingerprint reader.");
    UpdateWindow(hStaticWnd);
    ShowWindow(hMainWnd, SW_SHOW);
    SetForegroundWindow(hMainWnd);
    LockSetForegroundWindow(LSFW_LOCK);
    hr = WinBioVerify(
        sessionHandle,
        &identity,
        WINBIO_SUBTYPE_ANY,
        &unitId,
        &match,
        &rejectDetail
    );
    CString msg;
    msg.Format("Swipe processed - Unit ID: %d\n", unitId);
    OutputDebugString(msg);

    lsr.Format("globals.last_scan_result = %d", globals.last_scan_result);
    OutputDebugString(lsr);
    while (globals.last_scan_result == BIO_INPROGRESS)
    {
        OutputDebugString("Waiting for verify...");

        lsr.Format("globals.last_scan_result = %d", globals.last_scan_result);
        OutputDebugString(lsr);

        MSG msg;
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) break;
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        else if (globals.last_scan_result == BIO_INPROGRESS)
        {
            WaitMessage();
        }
    }
    OutputDebugString("Waiting for verify DONE.");

    if (globals.last_scan_result == BIO_INPROGRESS)
    {
        globals.last_scan_result = BIO_CANCEL;
    }
    lsr.Format("globals.last_scan_result = %d", globals.last_scan_result);
    OutputDebugString(lsr);
    ShowWindow(hMainWnd, SW_HIDE);
    LockSetForegroundWindow(LSFW_UNLOCK);
    if (sessionHandle != NULL)
    {
        /*
        if (globals.last_scan_result == BIO_CANCEL || globals.last_scan_result == BIO_TIMEOUT)
        {
            WinBioCancel(sessionHandle);
            //WinBioWait(sessionHandle);
        }
        */
        WinBioCloseSession(sessionHandle);
        sessionHandle = NULL;
    }
    return globals.last_scan_result;
} catch (...) {
    OutputDebugString("Verify catch Error");
}
return BIO_ERROR;
```

}

Here's the code that doesn't work on Win7:

```
unsigned int verifyUser7(string &userName) {

string libPath;

OutputDebugString("verifyUser7: getApplicationPath");

libPath = getApplicationPath();
//  HWND capwnd;


try {

    //Make sure path ends with backslash
    if (libPath[libPath.length() - 1] != '\\') libPath += "\\";
    string  userHash = getHash(userName);

    //Get timeout from globals
    int timeoutValue = globals.timeout * 1000;

    //Check to see if we need an infinite timeout
    if (globals.disable_timeout)
    {
        timeoutValue = 1000 * 60 * 5;
    }
    TotalTickCount = timeoutValue; //5 minutes
    startTick = GetTickCount();
    globals.last_scan_result = BIO_INPROGRESS;
    countdownTimer = SetTimer(hMainWnd, ID_COUNTDOWN, 1000, NULL);

    CString lsr;
    lsr.Format("globals.last_scan_result = %d", globals.last_scan_result);
    OutputDebugString(lsr);

    sessionHandle = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = WinBioOpenSession(
        WINBIO_TYPE_FINGERPRINT,    // Service provider
        WINBIO_POOL_SYSTEM,         // Pool type
        WINBIO_FLAG_DEFAULT,        // Configuration and access
        NULL,                       // Array of biometric unit IDs
        0,                          // Count of biometric unit IDs
        NULL,                       // Database ID
        &sessionHandle              // [out] Session handle
    );
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        CString s;
        s.Format("WinBioOpenSession failed. hr = 0x%x\n", hr);
        OutputDebugString(s);
        KillTimer(hMainWnd, countdownTimer);
        ShowWindow(hMainWnd, SW_HIDE);
        LockSetForegroundWindow(LSFW_UNLOCK);
        if (sessionHandle != NULL)
        {
            WinBioCloseSession(sessionHandle);
            sessionHandle = NULL;
        }
        return BIO_ERROR;
    }

    // Find the identity of the user.
    WINBIO_IDENTITY identity = { 0 };
    hr = GetCurrentUserIdentity(&identity);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        CString s;
        s.Format("User identity not found. hr = 0x%x\n", hr);
        OutputDebugString(s);
        KillTimer(hMainWnd, countdownTimer);
        ShowWindow(hMainWnd, SW_HIDE);
        LockSetForegroundWindow(LSFW_UNLOCK);
        if (sessionHandle != NULL)
        {
            WinBioCloseSession(sessionHandle);
            sessionHandle = NULL;
        }
        return BIO_USER_NOT_ENROLLED;
    }

    // Verify a biometric sample.
    WINBIO_UNIT_ID unitId = 0;
    WINBIO_REJECT_DETAIL rejectDetail = 0;
    BOOLEAN match = FALSE;
    OutputDebugString("Calling WinBioVerifyWithCallback");
    SetWindowText(hStaticWnd, "To sign in, scan your finger on the fingerprint reader.");
    UpdateWindow(hStaticWnd);
    ShowWindow(hMainWnd, SW_SHOW);
    SetForegroundWindow(hMainWnd);
    LockSetForegroundWindow(LSFW_LOCK);
    hr = WinBioVerifyWithCallback(
        sessionHandle,
        &identity,
        WINBIO_SUBTYPE_ANY,
        VerifyCallback,             // Callback function
        NULL                        // Optional context
    );
    CString msg;
    //msg.Format("Swipe processed - Unit ID: %d\n", unitId);
    //OutputDebugString(msg);

    lsr.Format("globals.last_scan_result = %d", globals.last_scan_result);
    OutputDebugString(lsr);
    while (globals.last_scan_result == BIO_INPROGRESS)
    {
        OutputDebugString("Waiting for verify...");

        lsr.Format("globals.last_scan_result = %d", globals.last_scan_result);
        OutputDebugString(lsr);

        MSG msg;
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) break;
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        else if (globals.last_scan_result == BIO_INPROGRESS)
        {
            WaitMessage();
        }
    }
    OutputDebugString("Waiting for verify DONE.");

    if (globals.last_scan_result == BIO_INPROGRESS)
    {
        globals.last_scan_result = BIO_CANCEL;
    }
    lsr.Format("globals.last_scan_result = %d", globals.last_scan_result);
    OutputDebugString(lsr);
    ShowWindow(hMainWnd, SW_HIDE);
    WinBioReleaseFocus();
    //LockSetForegroundWindow(LSFW_UNLOCK);
    if (sessionHandle != NULL)
    {
        WinBioCloseSession(sessionHandle);
        sessionHandle = NULL;
    }
    return globals.last_scan_result;
}
catch (...) {
    OutputDebugString("Verify catch Error");
}
return BIO_ERROR;
```

}

Comment: `SetForegroundWindow` works as advertised on Windows 7. We need to see your code.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by adding SetFocus() after SetForegroundWindow(). Not sure why this extra step is necessary on Windows 7.